# Force Inherited ComboBox' DropDownStyle Property to DropDown

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, combobox

In VB.NET (WinForms), how to force a control that inherits `ComboBox` to only allow `DropDown` for its `DropDownStyle` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DropDownStyle property is not Overridable, that limits the amount of forcing your can do.  The approach that .NET Framework takes is to just hide the property.  Similar to:

```
Private Const DefaultStyle As ComboBoxStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.DropDownStyle = DefaultStyle
End Sub

<Browsable(False), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)>
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
Public Overloads Property DropDownStyle As ComboBoxStyle
    Get
        Return MyBase.DropDownStyle
    End Get
    Set(value As ComboBoxStyle)
        MyBase.DropDownStyle = DefaultStyle
    End Set
End Property
```

The Browsable attribute hides the property from the designer, the EditorBrowsable attribute hides it from the text editor, the DesignerSerializationVisibility ensures it is not written to the InitializeComponent() method.

But that doesn't otherwise stop client code, if it really wants to then it can cast to ComboBox and bypass your property setter, still assigning the MyBase.DropDownStyle property to an arbitrary value.  The liability of `Overloads` only hiding the base member and not overriding it.  Technically you can still defeat that by overriding CreateParams but the property is used too often in the ComboBox code to make that truly effective.  This is as good as it gets.  Good enough for the framework.

Comment: To stop client code from setting `DropDownStyle` to a different value, you can override `OnDropDownStyleChanged` and set `MyBase.DropDownStyle = DefaultStyle`

Comment: @RezaAghaei
That would technically change the `DropDownStyle` value and then back to `DropDown`. Not quite clean and might lead to undesirable side effects when the child's `DropDownStyle` event is triggered...

Comment: @Makaveli84 What I said, should be done *in addition to* the existing solution to prevent changing `DropDownStyle` using client code. You should know `OnDropDownStyleChanged` is simply responsible for raising `DropDownStyleChanged` event and nothing else. So it's safe to override it without needing to raise the event. To understand what I said, try `DirectCast(derivedComboBox, ComboBox).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei
Yeah, the "in addition to the existing solution part" was quite obvious, wasn't it?
I tried with `CType(MyNewComboBox1, ComboBox).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`, but that's probably the same as `DirectCast` in our case.. Isn't it?
To understand what you said? I did. Now for you to understand what I said, try overriding while raising the event: `MyBase.OnDropDownStyleChanged(e)`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Well, I'm sure you did understand. I shouldn't be making assumptions that you didn't. And while you are right in that it's safe to suppress the event by eliminating the needless `MyBase.OnDropDownStyleChanged(e)` call, the fact remains that your addition still causes the `DropDownStyle` to change back and forth, something that is evident in the `Paint` "flicker".

Comment: @Makaveli84 The addition is required if you want to prevent some invalid assignment like this `DirectCast(derivedComboBox, ComboBox).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`. It doesn't have any impact on cases that you assign valid value to property. That's it. Don't use it if you don't like it.